# Do datatypes influence how much memory is used? Does the final keyword change it?

Tags: java, memory, types, final

I don't know much about how memory actually works, but I wanted to know if storing the number 28 (5 bits) takes up different amounts of memory when it's stored as an int, long, short or byte? Does the final keyword limit the memory usage to only the number of bits required?

I couldn't think of a way to test this nor did I find anything about this online.

Comment: Yes, different types use different amount of memory: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

Comment: @UnholySheep so here I should use byte? Isn't there any option that would use only half a byte?

Comment: Not in Java, no. Also that type of thing sounds like a pre-mature optimization (which would quite likely turn into a pessimization, as reading and writing unaligned/non-byte sized integers is not natively supported on many CPU architectures, requiring a lot of extra instructions to be used)

Comment: Not even C or assembly let you do that, as the CPU eventually works with (multiples of) bytes. You can cram more than one variable in one e.g. byte and then use bitwise operations to pull out the 0parts you want, but this will make your code much more complicated for no good reason. The only exception is when you talk to certain hardware or network protocols that require certain memory layouts. Also: before trying to optimize, use a profiler. Citing Knuth: Premature optimization is the root of all evil.

Comment: @UnholySheep so am I understanding this right that any type uses the amount of memory in the documentation and just fills the unused bits with zeroes? So therefore the closer I can get to the actual size of my variable the more memory I'll save? So here I should use byte instead of int?

Comment: Maybe? It depends entirely on how and where you use these variables. And also whether this tiny memory saving actually benefits the code in any way (as mentioned above, you should always be profiling first).

Comment: @UnholySheep I need to store about a thousand variables in an array so I guess you're probably right I wouldn't save all that much space. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @UnholySheep Also, could you please write your first comment into an answer so I can accept it. And could you also include that the final keyword doesn't effect anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Limiting the datatype may indeed limit the space needed to store it.** But your example of 5 bits will still occupy at least 8 bits in memory, it will be rounded up.

As a variable (constant or not) in an object, **it will probably be zero padded** so that each property starts on an even "word" address. A word is the preferred integer size, typically 64 bits on a desktop computer or smaller for embedded or iot devices. So 5 properties of 1 byte each will occupy 5x64 bits on a 64 bit computer.

But **an array of bytes** (byte = 8 bits) will however only allocate one byte per element (and possibly zero pad at the end of the entire array to become an even word size), so here it will definitely matter when it comes to storage size.

**constants (static final) will occupy less space** because they are only stored once in metaspace, the static class memory. As you instantiate new objects of your class, constant values are not copied to the object space on the heap. Instead, each time the value is read, it's just read from the class definition in metaspace.

When it comes to performance, **an array of bytes will also occupy less space in caches** (more data will fit) and that will increase performance. If you are working with a GPU, or the CPU (and compiler) supports [SIMD](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_instruction,_multiple_data) instructions, you can gain a lot of performance using 8, 16 or 32 bits integers on a 64-bit computer.

Small constants, like 2147483000 (31 bits), can actually work a bit if luck outperform a bigger number like 8589934000 (33 bits)! But this is not something that you should define your program architecture at all, but seen more as **fun fact**.  Reason for the possible extra performance is that in can be embedded directly as a constant in some assembler instructions. The entire instruction must fit in 64 bits. This includes the actual instruction, the result register, and the constant. Example [LDR rd, =const](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0204/j/writing-arm-assembly-language/loading-constants-into-registers/loading-with-ldr-rd---const?lang=en). The const will not fit if its 64 bits, but a 31 bit const will!

Answer (score 2):

Actually you got the wrong impression of the usage of  the final keyword .

Each data type is allocated a fixed memory when it is declared and this memory is not permanent It is taken back into ram when the variable is no more used hence saving space.This kind of memory is known as stack.
.

And for the final keyword it stops the user from changing the value of the variable .

When a variable is declared with final keywork say :

```
final int i = 0; 
// Then if I try to give this another value say:
i = 12;
// I will get an error on line 3 because I am trying to change the 
// value of a final variable which is not legal
```

I will get an error it basically converts a variable into a constant value.

This types of variables are widely used in the industry for giving the names to specific values or defining an identity variable which is not meant to be changed

Comment: I know, but since the final keyword doesn't allow me to change the variable I thought that maybe it would only use the amount of space needed, since there will never be more necessary.

Comment: Exactly, small final numbers will most often be baked into the code itself rather than the heap or stack.

Answer (score 1):

Primitive data types use different amounts of memory, as explained in e.g.: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html

However, having any object in memory take less than 1 byte would not be helpful, since the hardware cannot work with anything smaller than that, therefore it is not supported. (There are ways of storing multiple different values in any single integer by using bit shifting/masking, but that is a different technique)

It is also important to note that before trying to optimize such memory use you need to profile first to see whether there would be any benefit to such an optimization.

The `final` keyword also has no effect on how large the memory for a variable will be, since those still have to follow the general rules of the language.